# Direction of data storage/loading in pandas for

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, plotly-dash

first post so please be gentle. I have very limited programming knowledge as I come from a more mechanical background, but I've learned some basics in python...

We collect scrape data daily on a excel spreadsheet for 1 month, what I'm trying to do is display the data on dashboard for ease of tracking trends etc. (I've been playing around with plotly.dash)
I'm reading excel.xlsx with pandas with MultiIndex. Currently I have 2 years (or 24 spreadsheets) worth of this data that I would like to use. Example below.

```
|Date      |  Batch| Qty Good| Thin| ...| Other| Qty Bad|                 
|01/11/2018| XY1234|   118147|    0| ...|     0|       0|
|01/11/2018| XY1235|   115454|  894| ...|     0|       0|
|02/11/2018| XY1236|   118900|  108| ...|     0|       0|
|...       |    ...|      ...|  ...| ...|   ...|     ...|

[108 rows x 225 columns]
```

My question is it better to convert everything to .csv then combine it as a database for initial start up of the program and then read the new data as .xlsx or is there more efficient (and/or better) way?

Any direction or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Pandas can read both csv and xlsx formats, in terms of what's more efficient that's subjective. If you're going to continue collecting data, it might make sense to store it in a database. But if you must keep the data in spreadsheets then you'd need to read all the files and combine them into a single dataframe is you want to use the 24 files for trending.

Comment: Another option here would be to check out [Mito][1] - which full disclaimer, I'm a creator of. It's a tool meant for making Excel/pandas transitions much easier and might be of interest to you!

[1] https://trymito.io